# Gulp and injected path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-inject

in visual studio i have the following client side project struture

```
-wwwroot
   -app
      -js
      -views
   -css
   -images
   -lib
   index.html
```

With gulp-inject i want inject the path of my javascript inside the index.html:

```
gulp.task('injecttest', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('wwwroot/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['wwwroot/app/js/**/*.js'], { read: false });

    return target.pipe(inject(sources)).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/'));;
});
```

**The gulpfile.js is outside the wwwroot directory.**
The problem here is that inside my index.html, the injected are in the form of:

```
<script src="/wwwroot/app/js/RemoteCallServices.js"></script>
```

and to work i need to have

```
<script src="app/js/RemoteCallServices.js"></script>
```

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gulp-inject [ignorePath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#optionsignorepath) option

```
gulp.task('injecttest', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('wwwroot/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['wwwroot/app/js/**/*.js'], { read: false });

    return target.pipe(inject(sources, { ignorePath: '/wwwrooot/')).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/'));;
});
```

Comment: This works for me, though instead if `src="app/js/etc..."` I get `src="/app/js/etc..."`. Any idea how to remove that additional leading `/`?

Comment: Remove the additional leading `/` from the ignorePath property. Using the above example, `{ ignorePath: 'wwwrooot/' }`

Comment: Update: in [this thread](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/issues/28) I saw that I can use `addRootSlash: false` as well as `ignorePath: '/wwwrooot/'`. Fixed it for me.